# Re sizing array

Tags: c#

```
int oldLength = numbers.Length;
int[] arrTmp = numbers;                  
numbers = new int[oldLength - 1];
Array.Copy(arrTmp, numbers, Token);
Array.Copy(arrTmp, r+1, numbers, Token, oldLength - Token - 1);
```

This all i got to remove a specified element from a value type array but it doesn't work.

I got 4 elements of value type array. I have stored 4 different numbers in it.

```
array[0] = 2;
array[1] = 4;
array[2] = 6;
array[3] = 8;
```

i got a random class to randomly pick a number if it is 2 has to be removed from my array in an ascending sequential order each element should be inspected and eliminated.

Comment: Any reason for not using collections?

Comment: Arrays have fixed length, so "resizing" involves actually creating a new array and copying element values over. You can do that with `Array.Resize(ref numbers, newLength);`.

Comment: @Jeppe: OP is actually creating a new array (`numbers`) and copying there from the source array (`arrTmp`).

Comment: What is `Token` and what is `r+1`? Is `Token` an element of the original array and `r` its index?

Answer (score 2):

You would do much easier using the [List class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

```
List<int> l = new List<int>();
l.Add(2);
l.Add(4);
...
l.Remove(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int oldLength = numbers.Length;
int[] arrTmp = new int[oldLength - 1];
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < oldLength || j < arrTmp.Length; i++)
{
    if(numbers[i] == Token)
        continue;
    arrTmp[j++] = numbers[i];
}
```

using linq:

```
var newArray = numbers.Where(n=> n!= Token).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use plain arrays and copy their contents using `Array.Copy` (which is not a common way of handling things in .NET), then start by using a **pen** and **write down correct indices and lengths** of the array parts you are trying to copy.

Starting to code the solution before you know how to solve it won't get you far.

So, start with an example array and a random index:

```
// starting array
int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

// index to remove 
int indexToRemove = new Random().Next(array.Length);
```

Now, presume that `indexToRemove` is `3` and try to do it by hand:

- Part 1: `{ 0, 1, 2 }` (start = `0`, length = `3`)
- Part 2: `{ 4, 5, 6, 7 }` (start = `4`, length = `4`)

From this concrete example, you can try to infer the general formula for offset and length of these two array parts:

- Part 1: start = `0`, length = `(indexToRemove - 1)`
- Part 2: start = `(indexToRemove + 1)`, length = `(array.Length - indexToRemove - 1)`

The code itself is then trivial:

```
var len = array.Length;
var newArray = new int[len - 1];
Array.Copy(array, 0, newArray, 0, indexToRemove - 1);
Array.Copy(array, indexToRemove + 1, newArray, indexToRemove, len - indexToRemove - 1);
```

Additionally, the `Array.Copy` can be used to copy a part of an array over itself, which means you can just move the second part of the array back by one position, and then resize the initial array using [`Array.Resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx):

```
// do not create a new array, but simply "move" the 2nd part to left    
Array.Copy(array, indexToRemove + 1, array, indexToRemove, len - indexToRemove - 1);

// finally, resize the original array
Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length - 1);
```

Of course, if you simply used a `List<int>`, then you would simply use the [`List<T>.RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx) method to remove the item:

```
var list = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int indexToRemove = new Random().Next(list.Count);
list.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the general approach:

```
int oldLength = numbers.Length;
int[] arrTmp = numbers;                  
numbers = new int[oldLength - 1];
Array.Copy(arrTmp, numbers, r);
Array.Copy(arrTmp, r + 1, numbers, r, oldLength - r - 1);
```

Note the use of `r` everywhere. Here `r` would be the index of the element to omit.